# Associative table and Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say that I have tree tables User, Product and UserProduct.

A user can have many products, and a product can be assigned to many users.

I want to retrive all the users product with linq. I created this method in the User.cs class :

```
    public List<Product> GetProductList()
    {
        List<Product> listProduct = new List<Product>();
        List<UserProduct> listUserProduct = this.UserProdutcs.ToList();

        foreach (var item in listUserProduct )
        {
            listProduct.Add(item.Product);
        }

        return listProduct; 
    }
```

I want to know if there is a better way of doing so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LINQ` and project into an anonymous type:

```
var newList = (from products in listProduct
           join uProducts in listUserProduct on products.id equals uProducts.productId
           select new {
                ProductDescription = products.Description,
                ProductAttribute = products.YourAttributes,
                ProductUserProductAttribute = uProducts.YourAttribute
           }).ToList();
```